# C++ const reference declaration

Tags: c++, declaration

how can the following declaration be expressed with const first (without typedef)?

```
double* const (&data)[6]
// ?? const double* (&data)[6] // incorrect, elements, not reference, are const
```

thank you

Comment: There is nothing called a const reference. It is always reference to a const, mostly that people refer to

Comment: Putting the 'const' after the star is what makes the pointers be 'const' rather than the things pointed to.  You can't put it first and have it mean what you seem to want it to mean.  That said, I very strongly suspect that declaration is just plain wrong.  Array of references to const pointers to mutable doubles?  Is that really what you want?

Comment: @Zack constant array of non-const pointers reference, yes

Comment: "Array of references to const pointers to mutable doubles?" ?  It looks to me like one reference to an array of const pointers to mutable doubles.

Comment: @Win you may be right, this declarations confuse me somewhat

Comment: In this list of comments it looks like Zack is confused not aaa.

Comment: Yeah, I always mix up what parentheses do in this context.  It still seems like it can't possibly be what you want though.

Comment: The actual meaning of the declaration is: *reference to array of 6 const pointers to non-const doubles*, and it is the only way you can write that without changing the meaning. What do you want declared? `const double * (&data)[6]`, as you have already noticed, means *reference to array of 6 non-const pointers to const doubles*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it.

According to the C++ Standard 8.3.2/1:

> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except
>   when the cv-qualifiers are introduced through the use of a typedef (7.1.3) or of a template type argument
>   (14.3), in which case the cv-qualifiers are ignored.

Comment: "Cv-qualified references" -- In the question there is a sample line of code and a commented out sample line of different code, neither of which attempts to create a cv-qualified reference.  Of course the first line of your answer is correct, but I'm not sure why you followed it with other stuff.

Comment: As I understand from the question he is trying to get const qualified reference.

Comment: Oh I see, the other comment inside the commented out line of code. You're right, your quotation from the standard answers that part. Somehow from the question, the valid line of code, and the code in the commented out line of code, I didn't figure out that's what he wanted.

Comment: My bet is that he actually wants the *pointer*, not the reference, to be constant, but that he does not like having the `const` placed in the intermediate position...